# Font looking different in MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I was checking this site:http://www.thecentrefordermatology.com/ I designed in Macbook Pro. The font of the "Read More" button looks different in Macbook. It was fine in Windows PC. What's the reason for this?

Comment: What font did you stipulate in your code for that button?  If it is not installed by default on both Win and Mac it will display differently.

Comment: Are you using Safari or a different browser?

Answer (score 5):

According to the Web Inspector you are using "Roboto" as font-family for the button.

[image]

This font isn't installed on macOS (at least not on a standard installation) so the browser falls back to its standard "sans-serif" font (which probably is Arial).